# Decode and restore CryptoJS encoded binary file back to it's original content

Tags: encryption, file-upload, cryptography, cryptojs

I am writing a File Uploader script that supports encryption for any file types before uploading. The target upload server is a PHP script that handles the upload and decrypt the encrypted data back to its original state.

I have written a CryptoJS encoder in JavaScript like this:

```
var files = document.getElementById('encrypt-input').files;
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('12345');
    var iv =  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("abcdef9876543210abcdef9876543210");

    function readFile(index) {

        if (index >= files.length) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php',
                data: {
                    files: JSON.stringify(formData)
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data) {
                    toastr.success('Your files have been uploaded safely!', 'Yahoo!');
                    step(1);
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    toastr.error('Something went wrong with the upload! Please check uploader logs for more details.', 'Stop1');
                }
            });
            return;
        }
        var file = files[index];

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(e.target.result, key, {iv: iv});
            sfu_encrypted[index] = {
                name: file.name,
                type: file.type,
                data: encrypted.ciphertext.toString()
            };
            readFile(index + 1)
        }
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
    readFile(0);
```

Now I'm stuck at decrypting the encrypted, write the file back to it's original state in PHP. So when I have a text file uploaded on my local computer, I should be able to read it from the uploaded file on the server.

The aim for this project is to secure file uploads using CryptoJS AES.

Comment: If you're using only symmetric encryption you need the exact same key at the server and the client. If you send the encryption key from the server to the client or the other way around you need to encrypt your symmetric encryption key. The easiest way to do this would be to use TLS. If you use TLS, then the data as well as key are encrypted, so you don't need to encrypt it yourself. This doesn't provide any security, just a little bit of obfuscation. You should read: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Comment: Will the files be saved on the server encryted? Where will they be decrypted? If the file will be saved un-encrypted on the server, that is the encryption is only used during the trasfer between the local computer and the server just use HTTPS.